# Error "mscoreei.dll not found" in VS2015 debugging

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

When I'm trying to debug my dump file I get an error:

> mscoreei.dll not found
>
> mscoreei.dll was not found in the minidump. You need to load the binary in order to find the source for the current stack frame.

I have a project in C# that can hang sometimes on other computer. Each time as it hangs, 'procdump' app creates minidump file for me. Previously, I could normally open this dump file in VS2015, which shows me a stuck place in the source code.

Everything works fine till I made a 'clean up' in the repository. I didn't add any line in the code, I just clean up repository and all my .pdb files were exterminated. I build project again to restore .pdb files. But now as I try to debug dump files, VS2015 shows me page "No Binary Found" with error message written above.

I didn't make any changes in the source code. I didn't modify my environment. Debugging stops working as I made repository clean up.

When I'm checking 'Stack Frame' list, then evrything that is coming after "mscoreei.dll!7311ffcc" have format "[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no binaries loaded for *filename*]".

Comment: that is the dll which contains CLR

Comment: well, if I create a new project and create a new dump file of this project, then everything works fine.

Comment: then most probably you messed up something in that solution which is causing problems

Comment: Having matching PDBs whose timestamp exactly matches the binaries on the machine you got the minidump from is critical.  You deleted them, big oops.  You are done with this session, update the machine with new binaries so the next minidump can work.   And make sure you keep those PDBs around, a source server is always best.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It turns out, that my environment changed. From the last build when debugging worked correctly, Windows Update service updated my .NET library. As result my new build is using updated .NET files, but dumps are created for old .NET. Restoring correct version of .NET helped me.